# replace-regexp query for custom highlighting for org-mode export

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.gonsie.com/blorg/org-highlight.html) blog post and add user-defined text markup to my org files for highlights in my html and latex-pdf exports.

- The *blog post includes a regex example* (which I referenced), but *their's doesn't (for me at least) work* correctly for any of the example cases detailed below, so *I'm trying to write my own, but I need some help.*

  - (Their logic from the blog adapted to use my highlight symbol (`@`) and latex output (`\hl{}`) I believe is as follows:)

```lisp
(let ((text (replace-regexp-in-string "[^\\w]\\(@\\)[^\n\t\r]+\\(@\\)[^\\w]" "\\\\hl{"  text nil nil 1 nil)))
        (replace-regexp-in-string "[^\\w]\\(\\\\hl{\\)[^\n\t\r]+\\(@\\)[^\\w]" "}" text nil nil 2 nil)))
```

---

(In org-mode) I am enclosing text I want to highlight in `@` symbols, and make the following conversion for latex highlighting.

- 1st @ -> \hl{
- 2nd @ -> }

Expected output of 4 inputs:

- @highlight me@ -> \hl{highlight me}
- Bill@highlight me@ -> Bill\hl{highlight me}
- @highlight me@Bob  -> \hl{highlight me}Bob
- @highlight me@ and @highlight me@ -> \hl{highlight me} and \hl{highlight me}

My org-mode code block to test regex logic on the 4 cases:

```lisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
    ; 4 regex cases to convert
    (setq mylist '("@highlight me@" "Bill@highlight me@" "@highlight me@Bob" "@highlight me@ and @highlight me@"))

    (defun highlight-attempt (text)
      "replace @text@ with \hl{text}"
        (let ((text (replace-regexp-in-string "[^\\w]\\(@\\)" "}" text nil nil 1 nil)))
          (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(^@\\)[^\\w]" "\\\\hl{" text nil nil 1 nil)))

  (mapcar 'highlight-attempt mylist)
  #+end_src
```

My current output from the above 4 inputs:

- @highlight me@ -> \hl{highlight me}

  - (as expected)
- Bill@highlight me@ ->  Bill}highlight me}

  - (not as expected)
- @highlight me@Bob  -> \hl{highlight me}Bob

  - (as expected)
- @highlight me@ and @highlight me@ ->  \hl{highlight me} and }highlight me}

  - (not as expected)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog uses incorrect regexps, refer to [elisp regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html).
Namely `[^\\w]` means anything that isn't a literal `\` or `w` - `\\w` isn't special within `[...]`.  Alternatives in elisp are `\\W` and `[^[:word:]]`.  I would use another approach and just keep the text between the outer '@'s

```
(replace-regexp-in-string
 "@\\([^@]+\\)@"
 ;; keep the inner text (match is '\\1' in replacement)
 "\\\\hl{\\1}"
 text)
```